# AS3 Performance with a Scaled Bitmap (or Shape fill)

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, bitmapdata

How costly is a draw of a scaled BitmapData?

Like many games, my game has a background image that spans the entire Stage.

That image is scaled to fit the dimensions of the Stage (which can be resized, although very seldom).

That image is also drawn on every frame (since it intersect with every dirty region)

So on every frame, Flash has to draw a scaled Bitmap - how costly is that?

Answer (score 0):

"That image is also drawn on every frame" - do you mean that the image is on the stage, and other `DisplayObjects` move over it, or that the contents of the image are redrawn every frame?

This isn't a simple question to answer and it really comes down to your use-case. Some points:

- If your image is being scaled down, then you're wasting memory more than anything else
- If you're drawing your image every frame, then, if you're scaling down, it's better to draw it to the final scale
- Don't worry too much about performance until it's a problem

If it's a static image, then you don't have much to worry about. Most of the rendering time in flash is taken up with the conversion of vector to raster - images don't have this, so it's mostly just copying the bytes to the display buffer. If you really want to go in-depth, then use Scout (http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/) which will give you pretty good info on render times, amongst other things.

Comment: The image is a Full HD static bitmap (PNG file originally) ---  
It spans the entire stage for Full Screen support (that's why it's being drawn every frame - everything intersects it) --- The stage can be resized (that's why I need the large bitmap; scaling it down on every resize is possible, but a bit tedious) --- So indeed, on every frame Flash has to draw a scaled version of the bitmap... and I wonder how costly is that... **is it only a matter of byte copying? what about smoothing?** isn't there a whole algorithm running to scale down the image? 10x for the help!

Comment: "scaling it down on every resize is possible, but a bit tedious" - resizing doesn't happen every frame (unless you can drag to resize), so it's probably worth it to redraw the bitmap if it'll help your perf on other frames. Smoothing is `false` by default, but if you have it active, then it will have an impact, yes. To see if it's really a problem for your game, use scout if you can

Comment: "it's being drawn every frame - everything intersects it" - I think you're confusing bitmap redraw with redraw regions. I'm not an expert on the internals of flash rendering, but it's something like this - in order to be displayed, your graphics need to be rasterised. Vector to raster takes the majority of the time for rendering. Bitmaps don't need to be rasterised as they already are (ignoring rotation and scale here for the min). To help speed, flash only redraws dirty regions of the screen - it doesn't really matter if your huge image or another one is in the bg

Comment: if you *test*, and if you see there's a problem, first try redrawing it to the proper size, then try breaking it up into smaller images, then try starling (if you're not already using it). for the most part, I don't think you'll have a problem, unless there's something specific for your game, and even then you'll probably get more benefit optimising other graphics than your bg

Comment: for info, we had an iso game running in starling, with a huge bg image (about 6 full spritesheets worth), and multiple hundreds of animating units walking across it, running at 60fps. Even then, the biggest perf problems were stuff like sorting

Comment: When a DisplayObject changes (move/scale/color/filters etc.) it triggers a dirty region... Flash combines all these regions in a frame into a maximum of 3 unified dirty regions and updates its pixel-matrix buffer according to those regions - a Dirty Region Update includes drawing ALL of the DisplayObjects in that region (even ones which didn't change or are in alpha=0 or are behind other objects) ...

Comment: ... so no matter what changes on screen - even a single pixel change - my BG image gets drawn (it lies behind that changing pixel as it spans the entire stage) - and I still wonder how costly it is that this image is scaled... I will use your advice and scout it - updates to come..